# How to convert a string in a FastReport 6.9 form to an integer?

Tags: sql, firebird, pascalscript, fastreport

I am creating a report, and when filling out a form, the variable is not working.

[image: Form]

[image: Qry]

But it's not returning any value to me; I believe the value is being passed as a string, but for it to work, it has to be an integer. How do I change the type?

**SQL**

```
SELECT  TORDEMPROD.NUM_CHAVE           AS "Chave da Ordem"
       ,Trim(TORDEMPROD.COD_EMPRESA)   AS "Código da Empresa"
       ,TEMPRESA.DES_RAZSOCIAL         AS "Razão Social Empresa"
       ,TEMPRESA.DES_FANTASIA          AS "Fantasia Empresa"
       ,TORDEMPROD.COD_DOCOP           AS "Código do Documento"
       ,Trim(TORDEMPROD.NUM_ORDEMPROD) AS "Numero da Ordem"
       ,TORDEMPROD.TIP_PRODUTO         AS "Tipo Produto"
       ,TORDEMPROD.COD_PRODUTO         AS "Código Produto"
       ,TPRODUTO.DES_PRODUTO           AS "Descricao do Produto"
       ,TPRODUTO.DES_COMPLMAT          AS "Complementar do Produto"
       ,TORDEMPROD.DES_OBS
       ,CASE WHEN TORDEMPROD.STA_PLANEJAMENTO = 1 THEN 'Planejado'
             WHEN TORDEMPROD.STA_PLANEJAMENTO = 2 THEN 'Firmado'
             WHEN TORDEMPROD.STA_PLANEJAMENTO = 2 THEN 'Simulado'
             WHEN TORDEMPROD.STA_PLANEJAMENTO = 4 THEN 'Firmado com Alteracao' END AS STAPLANEJAMENTO
       ,CASE WHEN TORDEMPROD.STA_ATENDIMENTO = 0 THEN 'Totalmente em Aberto'  WHEN TORDEMPROD.STA_ATENDIMENTO = 1 THEN 'Atendido Parcialmente'  WHEN TORDEMPROD.STA_ATENDIMENTO = 2 THEN 'Atendido Totalmente' END AS STATENDIMENTO
       ,TORDEMPROD.QTD_PRODUZIR
       ,TPRODUTO.SIG_UNIDADE
       ,TUNIDADE.DES_UNIDADE
       ,TORDEMPROD.DAT_NECESSARIA
       ,TMRP.COD_DOCMRP
       ,TMRP.NUM_MRP
       ,TMRP.DES_MRP
FROM TORDEMPROD
INNER JOIN TEMPRESA
ON TEMPRESA.COD_EMPRESA = TORDEMPROD.COD_EMPRESA
INNER JOIN TPRODUTO
ON TPRODUTO.TIP_PRODUTO = TORDEMPROD.TIP_PRODUTO AND TPRODUTO.COD_PRODUTO = TORDEMPROD.COD_PRODUTO AND TPRODUTO.COD_EMPRESA = TORDEMPROD.COD_EMPRESA
INNER JOIN TUNIDADE
ON TPRODUTO.SIG_UNIDADE = TUNIDADE.SIG_UNIDADE
INNER JOIN TMRP
ON TORDEMPROD.COD_EMPRESA = TMRP.COD_EMPRESA AND TORDEMPROD.NUM_CHMRP = TMRP.NUM_CHAVE
WHERE TORDEMPROD.NUM_ORDEMPROD = :NUM_CHAVEOP
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a BeforePrint method for your Cell/TextObject in the code section. Then
you can use  (int)Report.GetColumnValue("DataName.ColumnName");

[image: Code Section]

[image: BeforePrint Method]

Comment: did not work!!!

Comment: You should share a sample code. May be, I can have something then.